# Срок чтения книги

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как назвать период, в течение которого читатель имеет право пользоваться книгой? Срок содержания? Срок пользования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Время пользования** книгой (столько-то дней), **срок возврата** книги (такая-то дата).

> *Если вы не успели прочитать книгу за отведённое время, вам необходимо*
>   *предупредить библиотекаря о продлении **времени пользования** книгой.*

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=_pCJDQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA72&img=1&zoom=3&ots=vkjWpjmBwV&sig=ACfU3U25UM1dZtu4-Qrm5OkjdNBIEIzKfA&w=1280